# how to loop inside an array that is inside an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have problems while looping through an array. That is, inside an object which is inside of an array in javascript. Below is my loop and under is my object.
I want retrieve the names of the objects. please, compare my `$('#searchbox').keypress` function and my `var animals_data` object

```
$('#searchbox').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var search_text = $('#searchbox').val();
        console.log(search_text)
        var filteredData = {
            animalsR: animals_data.category.animalsR.filter(function(d){
                if (d.name.search(search_text) > -1){
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            })
        };

        var source   = $("#album-template-Reptile-result").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var html    = template(filteredData);
        $('#content').html(html);
    }
});

var animals_data = {
    category : [{
        name : "Reptiles",
        animalsR : [
            {
                image1 : "url" ,
                image2 : "url" ,
                name : "Snake",
                description : "text"
            },
            {
                image1 : "url",
                image2 : "url",
                name : "Crocodilia",
                description : "text"
            }
        ]
    }]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get first element in array via `[0]`, `category` in your case is an `Array`

```
animals_data.category.animalsR.filter
//                   ^---- your error here, it's an array
```

---

For iterating arrays you can use [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
animals_data.category[0].animalsR.forEach(function(e){
    // do something ...
})
```

---

> But what if I have many objects in the array category. Each of which contains an array that I want to itterate through.

For that you can use nested `Array.forEach()` method, like this:

```
animals_data.category.forEach(function(a) {
    a.animalsR.forEach(function(e) {
        // do something
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, all that I needed was category[0]. But what if I have many objects in the array category. Where each object contains an array that I want to iterate through. So I dont only have the "animalsR"-array, I would have more arrays inside.
 I would try to make the index generic. And also have the same name for each array (animalsR for example). 

animals_data.category[i].animalsR.filter{
//do stuff
}